# Laravel displaying model results based on a search query

Tags: laravel, model

I have Laravel medicines table in which medicine names are stored as

```
description = Verapamil 120mg tablets (IVAX Pharmaceuticals UK Ltd)
description = Verapamil 80mg tablets (Accord Healthcare Ltd)
```

The user can query the database like "*vera 10mg*" and "vera 120"
The user can write part of a word instead of full word to get the result.

Example when user type "***vera 80***" the result should be: "Verapamil 80mg tablets (Accord Healthcare Ltd)"

Example: Type "**ator 80 tev**" for "Atorvastatin 80mg tablets (Teva brand)"

Right now i am getting data with where clause and the user has to type full medicine name to get the results instead of part of it.

```
$data = DMD::where('description','like', '%'.$query.'%');
```

Comment: Just split the query string up on spaces, then do a `where("description", "LIKE", "%$word%")`. I'll see if I can write a full answer soon - but this should help you out for now.

Comment: Splitting with Explode only shows results based on first part of word , for example "vera" results are shown. "80" results are only shown after all "vera" results. I want first results to be re-filtered based on second query and so on.

Comment: you can also replace the spaces with `%`, but in that case the order of the words need to be correct "80 vera" will not give the results in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, though I haven't been able to verify this on a dummy server.

```php
$query = "vera 80";
$queries = [];
foreach (explode(" ", $query) as $word) {
    $queries[] = ["description", "LIKE", "%$word%"];
}
$data = DMD::where($queries);
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses), this is going to create an array of `AND WHERE` clauses.

---

Another alternative is the below.

```php
$query = "vera 80";
$data = DMD::query();
foreach (explode(" ", $query) as $word) {
    $data->where("description", "LIKE", "%$word%");
}
```

This version will create a basic query object for the database table.
Then we will split the string on spaces, and iterate through each word.

The `$data->where` line is mutating the object add adding a new `AND WHERE` clause to the database query.

---

As is the case in both examples, I haven't called the `get()` method on the `$data` object as I noticed that you didn't in your example.
Naturally, if you want to get your results you'll need to call this otherwise you'll just have a `Builder` instance.

Comment: DMD::query(); and it worked.

Comment: @AhtshamKhan Glad it's worked for you :)